# How can I immediately stop the program as in regular PHP in PHP extension in C?

Tags: php, c, exception

In regular PHP, when I connect to a database and execute a faulty SQL statement, PHP immediately stops the program and displays the error.

```
$conn = new PDO();
$sth = $conn->prepare('select2 * from block');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```

However, in a PHP extension with C, there seems to be a difference in behavior.

If I execute an incorrect SQL statement, the program still throws a fatal error exception, but the code after it continues to execute:

```
zval sql, model, result, tmp;
object_init_ex(&model, modelCe);
zend_call_method(Z_OBJ(model), Z_OBJCE(model), NULL, ZEND_STRL("__construct"), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
ZVAL_STRING(&sql, "select2 * from table");
zend_call_method(Z_OBJ(model), Z_OBJCE(model), NULL, ZEND_STRL("findAllBySql"), &result, 1, &sql, NULL); // Error here
zval_ptr_dtor(&sql);
zval_ptr_dtor(&model);
zval_ptr_dtor(&result);

zend_string *key = zend_string_init(ZEND_STRL("backendUrl"), 0);
zval *view = zend_read_property(Z_OBJCE_P(ZEND_THIS), Z_OBJ_P(ZEND_THIS), ZEND_STRL("view"), ZEND_FETCH_CLASS_SILENT, NULL);
zval *backendUrl = Z_OBJ_HT_P(view)->read_property(Z_OBJ_P(view), key, BP_VAR_IS, NULL, &tmp); // Trying to retrieve value from object but seems the view object does not have value anymore.
zend_string_release(key);
zval_ptr_dtor(&tmp);

char *link = globalConcatenateString((char *[]) { Z_STRVAL_P(backendUrl), "/instance/data" }, 2);
free(link);

RETURN_TRUE;
```

However, it seems that when an exception is thrown, the values of variables after the faulty statement are seemingly cleared, and at this point, the program crashes with a Segmentation fault error.

If I try to catch the exception in the **findAllBySql** function and then re-throw the error, it inadvertently makes the program more complicated, as I need to add exception checks for every database query (or any other function that throws an exception):

```
zend_call_method(Z_OBJ(model), Z_OBJCE(model), NULL, ZEND_STRL("findAllBySql"), &result, 1, &sql, NULL); // Error here

// Check exception:
if (EG(exception)) {
    // Handle error
}

// Call other query
zend_call_method(Z_OBJ(model), Z_OBJCE(model), NULL, ZEND_STRL("findAllBySql"), &result, 1, &sql, NULL); // Error here

if (EG(exception)) {
    // Handle error
}
```

How can I immediately stop the program as in regular PHP?

Comment: Immediately stop? Then who is going to call `zval_ptr_dtor`, `zend_string_release`, `free`, etc.?

Comment: Why can't I get the property value of the object as normal? Why does the system clear the object value? If the system clear the variable value, then how can it call zval_ptr_dtor, zend_string_release, free, etc properly?

Comment: I cannot answer the 1st question, and it seems to be another new question. As for the 2nd one, what does the the object refer to? `model`? What does clear mean? Based on the code you provided, I don't think `zend_call_method` has the ability to set these variables to NULL.

Comment: @shingo, this line, zval *backendUrl = Z_OBJ_HT_P(view)->read_property(Z_OBJ_P(view), key, BP_VAR_IS, NULL, &tmp); If I get the backendUrl property before call the zend_call_method, there is a not empty string, but if I get after the call, it returns NULL. I don't think the zend_call_method made it.

Comment: @ikegami, It does. It still execute the code after the error.

Comment: When the `findAllBySql` function throws an exception, you need to check `EG(exception)` and return false just like you did, but you also need to call `zval_ptr_dtor` on the 3 zvals before your function returns, so that you cannot immediately stop the program.

Comment: @shingo, As I said, I don't want to check the EG(exception) because it make the program complicated since we need to check for every line code (actually any line code can cause the ex). I found the root cause and it seems it is a PHP bug, because I'm using PHP 8.2, so the dynamic property is deprecated. I have added __get and __set for the View, however, after the system throw ex, this mechanism doesn't work anymore (it doesn't go to the __get method), and the property value return NULL instead of the value from the __get method. Now I extend the View from the stdClass and the issue is gone.

Comment: @ikegami, Unlike what regular PHP does, the behavior of the extension a bit different.

Comment: @ikegami, Please look into the part 2 of code, line 5 (zend_call_method), if we have a wrong sql, there will be a fatal error, but the program will still continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: @ikegami, PHP shown it with Fatal Error label. "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: But it was caught, and it wasn't fatal. Your question is literally how to make it fatal.

Comment: 2 things, first: In the PHP extension, after the fatal error thrown, the program still continue execute the code; second: The question is for my expect, because after the error sql line, the variable (view) with the __get and __set mechanism doesn't work as expected (seems PHP bug), the value of the view backendUrl property is NULL, this cause the Segmentation fault, so my expect is the program will not execute the code after the error sql line, then no Segmentation fault, then PHP can show the fatal error properly. Check my previous comment for how resolve the issue.